# How to get the i-th bit of an integer without bit shifting?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have a 16-bit integer `x` and I want to find out whether the `i`-th bit of `x` is 0 or 1. I'm not able to use bit shifts, but I can use a predefined array `twoToThe` of length 16 where `twoToThe[j]` holds 2 to the power of `j`. I think I can accomplish what I'm looking for using bitwise boolean operations, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. You can check to see whether `x & twoToThe[i]` is equal to 0. If it is, then it must be true that `i`-th bit of `x` is 0. If it's anything other than 0, then the `i`-th bit of `x` is 1.